# получить локальный ip компьютера

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip

```
import socket

hostname = socket.gethostname()
local_ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
```

получаю `socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfofailed`
как получить ip?
в C# делаю так и все работает

```
ipEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName());
addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
addr[0]; //192.168.0.158
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hostname` не записан ни в `etc/hosts`, ни в `winbind`, ни в какомто ещё ресолвере - поэтому возникает такая ошибка. В настроенных компьютерах там обычно 127.0.0.1

Запусти любой UDP сокет на любой внешний адрес и ядро построит маршрут. На сокете будет адрес который смаршрутизирован в данном направлении.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
print(s.getsockname()[0])
s.close()
```

Запросы никуда не отправляются

Comment: Каждый раз расписывать `("8.8.8.8", 80)` ????

Comment: нужен любой ip адрес в направлении интернета кроме специальных (0,0,0,0 255,255,255,255 и тп).

Comment: можно поставить ("1.1.1.1", 4500).

Answer (score 1):

Только под windows:

```
def getIPAddresses():
      from ctypes import Structure, windll, sizeof
      from ctypes import POINTER, byref
      from ctypes import c_ulong, c_uint, c_ubyte, c_char
      MAX_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH = 128
      MAX_ADAPTER_NAME_LENGTH = 256
      MAX_ADAPTER_ADDRESS_LENGTH = 8
      class IP_ADDR_STRING(Structure):
          pass
      LP_IP_ADDR_STRING = POINTER(IP_ADDR_STRING)
      IP_ADDR_STRING._fields_ = [
          ("next", LP_IP_ADDR_STRING),
          ("ipAddress", c_char * 16),
          ("ipMask", c_char * 16),
          ("context", c_ulong)]
      class IP_ADAPTER_INFO (Structure):
          pass
      LP_IP_ADAPTER_INFO = POINTER(IP_ADAPTER_INFO)
      IP_ADAPTER_INFO._fields_ = [
          ("next", LP_IP_ADAPTER_INFO),
          ("comboIndex", c_ulong),
            ("adapterName", c_char * (MAX_ADAPTER_NAME_LENGTH + 4)),
          ("description", c_char * (MAX_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH + 4)),
          ("addressLength", c_uint),
          ("address", c_ubyte * MAX_ADAPTER_ADDRESS_LENGTH),
          ("index", c_ulong),
          ("type", c_uint),
          ("dhcpEnabled", c_uint),
          ("currentIpAddress", LP_IP_ADDR_STRING),
          ("ipAddressList", IP_ADDR_STRING),
          ("gatewayList", IP_ADDR_STRING),
          ("dhcpServer", IP_ADDR_STRING),
          ("haveWins", c_uint),
          ("primaryWinsServer", IP_ADDR_STRING),
          ("secondaryWinsServer", IP_ADDR_STRING),
          ("leaseObtained", c_ulong),
          ("leaseExpires", c_ulong)]
      GetAdaptersInfo = windll.iphlpapi.GetAdaptersInfo
      GetAdaptersInfo.restype = c_ulong
      GetAdaptersInfo.argtypes = [LP_IP_ADAPTER_INFO, POINTER(c_ulong)]
      adapterList = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO * 10)()
      buflen = c_ulong(sizeof(adapterList))
      rc = GetAdaptersInfo(byref(adapterList[0]), byref(buflen))
      if rc == 0:
          for a in adapterList:
              adNode = a.ipAddressList
              while True:
                  ipAddr = adNode.ipAddress
                  if ipAddr:
                      yield ipAddr
                  adNode = adNode.next
                  if not adNode:
                      break
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/166992/11563491)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте бибилиотеку `geocoder`, Установить можно здесь https://pypi.org/project/geocoder/ с помощью команды `pip install geocoder`

```
# IP компьютера (g.ip)
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print("Your IP adress is..." + str(g.ip))

# Вся инфа по IP (g.json)
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print(str(g.json))

# Имя провайдера (g.hostname)
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print("Your hostname is..." + str(g.hostname))

# Название улицы (g.street)
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print("Your street name is..." + str(g.street))

# Почтовый код (g.postal)
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print("Your postcode number is..." + str(g.postal))

# Номер дома (g.housenumber)
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print("Your house number is..." + str(g.housenumber))

# Страна (g.country)
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print("Your country is..." + str(g.country))

# Город (g.city)
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print("Your city is..." + str(g.city))

# Штат (g.state)
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print("Your state is..." + str(g.state))

# Координаты (g.osm)
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print(str(g.osm))
```

Comment: библиотека делает запросы на http://ipinfo.io/json. вспоминается как старый прикол яваскриптеров "сложение как сервис")

Comment: Ну делает запросы, и что? Зато больше инфы и меньше кода! Удобно и практично!

Comment: а теперь прочти последнюю строчку вопроса >>> addr[0]; //192.168.0.158

Comment: @AlexZab тоже так думаю...питон предполагает удобное библиотеки

Comment: @VictorVosMottor в этом случае не питон, а 2 с половиной человека, которые написали этот комбаин. Удобно конечно, но медленно и не надежно.

Comment: @eri В этом вся суть СО. Один предложить сложно и надежно, другой просто и ненадежно, третий еще что-то. Пусть ТС выберет что ему больше нравится

Comment: Может я слепой но где она выводит `локальный` IP? Локальный это все таки IP на сетевой карте.

Comment: @AlexZab [Зачем вам второй аккаунт?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/555271)

Answer (score 0):

А еще так (`pip3 install netifaces`):

```
from netifaces import interfaces, ifaddresses, AF_INET
for ifaceName in interfaces():
    addresses = [i['addr'] for i in ifaddresses(ifaceName).setdefault(AF_INET, [{'addr':'No IP addr'}] )]
    print('%s: %s' % (ifaceName, ', '.join(addresses)))
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netifaces'

Comment: @eri ну там пипом надо поставить. А у меня и так стоит на 3.8 убунта 20.04. Ща отредакриую